# In GEO-MASHUP: How to open post directly when marker is clicked?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-geo-mashup

I created a contextual map to show posts of a certain category on a map. I would like the post to open directly when the user clicks on the marker on the map. How can I achieve this?

Geo-Mashup : Version 1.6.2
WordPpress version: WordPress 3.5.1

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must install the plugin Geo Mashup Custom. After that, access the plugin folder and create a js file. If you are using google v3 api create file custom-googlev3.js and then copy paste this code:

```
GeoMashup.addAction( 'selectedMarker', function( properties, marker, map ) {
  var objects = GeoMashup.getMarkerObjects( marker );
  if ( objects.length > 0 && GeoMashup.have_parent_access ) {
    parent.location.href = properties.home_url + '?p=' + objects[0].object_id;
  }
});
```

Please also read the [JavaScript API reference.](https://code.google.com/p/wordpress-geo-mashup/wiki/JavaScriptApi)